# How to make a top level drop down item clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, shopify, dropdown

Im making a store in shopify, and have set up the navbar as a dropdown.
 Clicking the nav links will only make it display or hide the drop down, but what i need is for it to, on the first click, display, then clicking the parent will follow the link.(for instance,my home item drops down, but i can't actually get home, and need it as a drop down item.)

```
HeaderView.prototype.events = {
"click .main-nav .dropdown > a": "toggleMenu",
};


HeaderView.prototype.toggleMenu = function(e) {
  var dropdown;
  e.preventDefault();
  dropdown = this.$(e.target).closest(".dropdown");
  if (!this.$(e.target).closest(".dropdown-nav").length) {
    this.$(".dropdown").not(dropdown).removeClass("active");
    return dropdown.toggleClass("active");}   
};
```

Obviously the e.preventDefault is stopping the link from working, but I'm not sure how to make it give an active class on the first click, then allow the link to be followed when the drop down is visible. It works with hover, but then won't work on touch devices.
 Any help/suggestions would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to call e.preventDefault() when you are doing the first click. Otherwise it is, like you said, preventing it from working.

Try this instead:

```
HeaderView.prototype.toggleMenu = function(e) {
    var dropdown;
    dropdown = this.$(e.target).closest(".dropdown");
    if (!this.$(e.target).closest(".dropdown-nav").length) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.$(".dropdown").not(dropdown).removeClass("active");
        return dropdown.toggleClass("active");
    }   
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response, I was going along the same line of thought and wound up with a simple, "if the class is active prevent default" type statement.

```
if (!this.$(".dropdown").hasClass("active")){
e.preventDefault();
```

So basically, if the drop down shows, allow the link, if isn't showing, prevent it;
thus keeping the top level as a link if it's drop down is 'open'.

```
HeaderView.prototype.toggleMenu = function(e) {
  var dropdown;
  dropdown = this.$(e.target).closest(".dropdown");
    if (!this.$(".dropdown").hasClass("active")){
  e.preventDefault();
  if (!this.$(e.target).closest(".dropdown-nav").length) {
    this.$(".dropdown").not(dropdown).removeClass("active");
    return dropdown.toggleClass("active");}
    }
};
```